# $$VAR stop working for QMAKE_RPATHDIR after update from Qt5.5 to Qt5.10.0

Tags: qt

In my pro file, there is a statement which use a variable defined in pri

project.pri

```
...
MYMODELDST      = ../../../mymodel/build/debug
...
```

subproj.pro

```
include( ../project.pri )
#...
QMAKE_RPATHDIR  += $${MYMODELDST}
#...
```

After update to Qt5.10.0, the link command change from:

> g++ -Wl,-rpath,/home/username/proj/mymodel/build/debug

to :

> g++ -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN/../../../mymodel/build/debug

I am wondering where does the "\$ORIGIN" come from.

Comment: one workaround is to set QMAKE_RPATHDIR  += $$PWD/$${MYMODELDST}

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is a result of a bug fix in qmake, the correct result is

```
g++ -Wl,-rpath,\$ORIGIN/../../../mymodel/build/debug
```

The $ORIGIN causes the runtime linker to look for the lib relative to the executable location.